# Does JSON deserialization into IEnumerable<T> yield the results?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

If I deserialize a JSON array into `IEunumerable<T>` using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package, will the library `yield` the results or deserialize the whole JSON array into `T[]`/`List<T>` and call `array.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: I could've debugged the code to find out but running it requires installing stuff that I don't really need e.g. .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this [code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/473a7721bd67cca8fef1ecc37da1951a1c180022/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonArrayContract.cs#L206), `Newtonsoft.Json` will change `IEunumerable<T>` to `List<T>` for deserializing, so the result of deserialize would be `List<T>`.

Comment: So to minimize processing/enumeration, it's best to deserialize a JSON array to a `List<T>`.